# Angular.js Interceptor close connection

Tags: angularjs

How to stop angularjs connection in between. Whenever I make a request and want to stop in between.
Is there any way to interscept the connection ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the solution.

```
connection.interceptor(function(){
```

})